# How can I get validators to work in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to implement validation in my ASP.NET Webforms application. Right now, the only validator that works is for the Date of Birth (DOB) field.  It is a custom field.

#### ASPX Code

```
<table>

      <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"> 
      <asp:Label ID="RegisterTitleID" runat="server">Register here for your New Account </asp:Label></td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EmailTextBox">E-mail:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px" 
              CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox></td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
            ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard" 
              Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="PasswordTextBox">Password:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
              Height="25px" Width="200px" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox></td> 
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="PasswordTextBox" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard" 
              Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>

      <tr>
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPasswordTextBox">Confirm Password:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="ConfirmPasswordTextBox" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
            ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>
      
      <tr> 
      <td align="center" colspan="2"> 
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
            ControlToCompare="PasswordTextBox" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPasswordTextBox" 
            Display="Dynamic" 
            ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
            ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard"> </asp:CompareValidator> </td> </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TitleTextBox">Title:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TitleRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TitleTextBox" ErrorMessage="Title is required." 
            ToolTip="Title is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FirstNameTextBox">First Name:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="FirstNameTextBox" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." 
            ToolTip="First Name is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="SurnameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="SurnameTextBox">Surname:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="SurnameTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SurnameRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="SurnameTextBox" ErrorMessage="Surname is required." 
            ToolTip="Surname is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="DOBTextBox">Date of Birth:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="DOBTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px">dd/mm/yyyy</asp:TextBox>
          </td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DOBRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="DOBTextBox" ErrorMessage="Date of birth is required." 
            ToolTip="Date of birth is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
           <asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
            ID="DateRangeCustomValidator" 
            ControlToValidate="DOBTextBox"
            onservervalidate="valDateRange_ServerValidate" 
            ErrorMessage="Enter a valid date. " />
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="GenderLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="GenderDropDownList">Gender:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>

           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="GenderRequired" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="GenderDropDownList" ErrorMessage="Gender is required." 
            ToolTip="Gender is required." ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="PhoneNumberLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="PhoneNumberTextBox">PhoneNumber:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="FavouriteTeamLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FavouriteTeamDropDownList">Favourite Team:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> 
          <asp:DropDownList ID="FavouriteTeamDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="Team" 
              DataTextField="Team" DataValueField="Team" Height="27px" Width="205px">
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Team" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RocoSportsDBConnectionString %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [Team] FROM [Team]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="MaritialStatusLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="MaritialStatusDropDownList">Maritial Status:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="MaritialStatusDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Separated</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Unmarried Relationship</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Domestic Partnership</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="EducationLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EducationDropDownList">Education:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="EducationDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Primary School</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Secondary School</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>College</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Undergrad</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Postgrad</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="ProfessionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ProfessionDropDownList">Profession:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ProfessionDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Management</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Professional</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Armed Forces</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Sales</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Adminstrative</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Farming</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Construction</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="SalaryLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="SalaryDropDownList">Salary:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="SalaryDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5000</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10000</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20000</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30000</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>50000</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>100000</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
            </tr>

      <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="EmploymentStatusLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EmploymentStatusDropDownList">EmploymentStatus:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="EmploymentStatusDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="27px" Width="205px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Unemployed</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Employed</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Self-employed</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Volunteer</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
            </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="right"> <asp:Label ID="InterestsLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="InterestsCheckBox">Interests:</asp:Label> </td>
      <td>
          <asp:CheckBoxList ID="InterestsCheckBox" runat="server" 
              onselectedindexchanged="InterestsCheckBox_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <asp:ListItem>Reading</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Football</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Swimming</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Basketball</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Cooking</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Music</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Philosophy</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Programming</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
   

      <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;"> <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>  </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"> <asp:Button ID="RegisterButton" runat="server" Text="Register" onclick="registerbutton_Click"/> </td> </tr>
      </table>
```

What could be the problem that's causing this code not to work, yet is not throwing any errors? Also, I'd like to position the validators better, and add color to them?

Comment: Please reformat and expand upon your question.  It's very unreadable in its current state.

Comment: Y u no try to give your `RegisterButton` the same `ValidationGroup` that others have?

Comment: Thank you that worked and I used validation summary to position my error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a ValidationGroup for all your validators except the DOB Custom validator.

Add it to your custom validator **and** also the Register Button.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
                ID="DateRangeCustomValidator" 
                ControlToValidate="DOBTextBox"
                onservervalidate="valDateRange_ServerValidate" 
                ErrorMessage="Enter a valid date. " 
        ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard"/>


<asp:Button ID="RegisterButton" runat="server" Text="Register"
 ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard" onclick="registerbutton_Click"/>
```

Comment: Indeed. @Sheesharp you need to make sure you include the `ValidationGroup="RegistrationWizard"` on all the validation controls

Answer (score 3):

You have `ValidationGroup` set on your validators but not on your button.